# Oblique projection in 3d pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

How can I make pgfplots to show the coordinate system from a view like in the following picture. The graph paper doesn't matter, but as you can see the x_1 axis should be relative to the graph paper trough the diagonals of the squares. Say if two squares are one unit for the x_2 and x_3 axis, one unit for the x_3 axis should be just a diagonal of *one* square.

[image]

Manipulating the view options didn't give the desired results:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmax=2.5,ymax=2.5,zmax=1.45,xlabel=$x_1$,ylabel=$x_2$,zlabel=$x_3$,axis lines=center,view={135}{45}]
    \addplot3[
        opacity=0.3,
        surf,
        shader=flat,
        samples=50,
        domain=-2:2,y domain=-2:2] 
        {exp(-(x^2+y^2))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Here the x_2 axis is not to the right.

Comment: I'm almost sure that you can't do [oblique projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_projection#Oblique_projection). You shouldn't do it anyways for proper data visualizations.

Comment: Thanks for the keyword "oblique projection". This leads me to the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percusse's comment provided the key word "oblique projection". Some googeling lead me to the following solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
        x={(-0.3535cm,-0.3535cm)},    
        y={(1cm,0.0cm)}, 
        z={(0cm,1cm)},
        xmax=2.5,ymax=2.5,zmax=1.45,
        xlabel=$x_1$,ylabel=$x_2$,zlabel=$x_3$,
        axis lines=center]
    \addplot3[
        opacity=0.3,
        surf,
        shader=flat,
        samples=50,
        domain=-2:2,y domain=-2:2] 
        {exp(-(x^2+y^2))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah you want to change the orientation... My bad. I misunderstood.

Comment: But this is an oblique, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You can format axis, and show a coordinate of your choice:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
    \begin{axis}[    
        axis x line = middle,
        axis y line = middle,
        axis z line = middle,   
        view={150}{35},
        domain =-5:5,
        y domain =-5:5,
        restrict z to domain =0:20,
        xmax =5,
        xmin =-5,
        ymax =5,
        ymin =-5,   
        zmax = 20,      
        zmin = 0,   
        xtick={-4,...,4},
        ytick={-4,...,4},
        ztick={0,4,...,20}
    ]
    \draw (4,4,16) node[above left] {\normalsize $A$};    
    \draw[dashed] (4,4,16)--(0,0,16);
    \draw[dashed] (4,4,16)--(4,4,0);
    \draw[dashed] (4,0,0)--(4,4,0)--(0,4,0);
    \filldraw (4,4,16)  circle(1pt);
    \filldraw (4,4,0)  circle(1pt);
    \filldraw (4,0,0)  circle(1pt);
    \filldraw (0,4,0)  circle(1pt);
    \filldraw (0,0,16)  circle(1pt);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and view={150}{35} command works fine, first part changes XOY plane, send rotates Z axis.

https://youtu.be/00S9l7pGkQY in this video I show some manipulations with plots. Language of video is georgian, but everything is clearly shown.

Comment: Thanks, but if I compile your example the x_2 axis doesn't point to the right.

Comment: it is done by xlable={$x$}, in video is shown how lables are added

Comment: This just add's the label. The orientation of the axis is wrong. Compare the picture in my question and in my solution.

Comment: I already wrote in answer orientation is set by  view={}{} command, by changing numbers you will chage orientation of axis, and choose which you will like.